# Why does not this NSAssert with stringWithFormat compile?

Tags: ios, nsassert

stringWithFormat should return a string, why does this statement not compile

```
NSAssert(YES, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"test if compiles"]);
```

when

```
NSAssert(YES, @"test if compiles");
```

compiles?

Comment: stringWithFormat with just a string again as a parameter in its format is redundant. I don't know exactly, but I believe, that Apple might have made some compiler level check on any such codes occurring. What error/message do you get when the assert doesn't compile ?

Comment: Extraneous closing brace

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this as :

```
NSAssert(YES, ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"test if compiles"])); // Pass it in brackets ()
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 15):

You don't actually need to use `stringWithFormat` at all. `NSAssert` *already expects* you to pass a format string and variable arguments for formatting. Given your example, you'll find this works just as well:

```
NSAssert(YES, "%@", @"test if compiles");
```

Or, a more realistic example:

```
NSAssert(i > 0, @"i was negative: %d", i);
```

The reason for your problem is because [`NSAssert` is a macro](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSAssert), defined like this:

```
#define NSAssert(condition, desc, ...)
```

And the compiler is confused because there's ambiguity between the parameter list for `stringWithFormat` and that of the macro itself. As Nishant points out, you can add brackets to avoid the confusion if you really want to use `stringWithFormat` here.